# Check if Soft navigation bar is present in windows mobile 10 and get its height and width

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-mobile, windows-10-mobile

Is there a way to check if soft navigation bar is present in windows mobile 10, is it possible to determine the height and width of the soft navigation bar?

Comment: What specific action will you take given this information?

Comment: Which soft navigation bar are you referring to?

Comment: Hi Rowland ,I am referring to the soft navigation bar present in the windows mobile 10 screen at the bottom, for navigation in the phone, it is the replacement for the hardware buttons.

Comment: Hi Peter, I am looking to show a splash screen in mainpage after the extended splash closes, however the splash screen image moves down a little when the mainpage shows up, i am using a relativepanel to make the splash exactly center, but it moves down, I have tried using the SetDesiredBounds(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible), however i still see it moving slightly down. I want the splash screen at the mainpage to appear exactly at the same coordintates as the default splash.